# Placing image on another image in Javascript

Tags: html, css, image

I am working in javascript. I am facing an issue i.e. I want to place an image on another image. MY Code is follows:

```
<div>
  <img src="1.jpg" style="z-index:1;"/>
  <img src="2.png" style="z-index:2; left:-100px;"/>
</div>
```

The problem is when i run the code it places image on the right bottom corner of the DIV but not on the image.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without taking the `<img>` out of the normal flow of the page, you'll have a job doing this. Read up on [positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Comment: [Link to tutorial](http://www.echoecho.com/csslayers.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3vZ/)

Use `position: absolute` in CSS:

```
img { position:absolute; }

<div>
  <img src="1.jpg"/>
  <img src="2.png"/>
</div>
```

Note: You don't need to specify `z-index` if you want last image to appear on top. This is default browser behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the position property to the image style, e.g. ->

```
position:relative
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position

Also, this isn't javascript, it's CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div>
  <img src="1.jpg" />
  <img src="2.png" style=" left:-100px; position:relative"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <img src="1.jpg" style="z-index:1;"/>
  <img src="2.png" style="z-index:2; position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: HAve you Skype ID ?? Please tell me I m online.

Comment: Sorry, I'm working right now, can't use skype. Try to edit your question to define exactly the problem, maybe you can add a working demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ and we try to help :)